# standalone dlux communication with opendaylight controller

Tags: opendaylight

1. We have cloned opendaylight controller and dlux into a machine
2. Did "mvn clean install" in opendaylight controller project and started it. By default odl-restconf-all bundle is not installed, as it is required, we installed it (it internally installed many dependent features which we could see using the command "feature list -i")

netstat -anp | grep ":8181"

this command confirmed us that the port is been consumed by the controller

3. Brought up the dlux server using the command "grunt live", it is listening on port number 9000

we also ensured that dlux-web/config/developement.json and production.json are pointing to the proper controller IP (as controller is running in a different OSGI container but same machine)

4. Launched the browser using the below url

http://localhost:9000/dlux/index.html
on the page "**Cannot GET /dlux/index.html**"

http://localhost:9000
**page is shown blank**

we have no idea what is missed in those to establish communication between them, can somebody let us know how to debug this issue?

or something from the dlux project should be pasted into the controller project?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the issue, found that app.module.js has some required variables commented, after enabling them, it started working.

no idea, why they are commented in that script

if someone has an idea about it, please update